# Javascript Fit Image Into Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html

I need to make my image fit into my div and I only want the picture to be inside the div. The rest of the picture will be behind the other elements.

Basically I want to achieve the same effect as here http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page.html but with the `<div id="background">`and `<div id="content">` that I have created.

As you can see first i gave `margin-bottom="350px` to the header in order to create a blank space, here i have the space for the img in my `div id="background"`which is located under (`z-index: -1;`) and the rest of the elements  is placed over inside the  the `div id="content"`  (`z-index:2;`)

Now I need Javascript which will fit this image into the `<div id="background">`. The image is not located between the menu-bar and the rest of the elements
Here you can look: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/10/

Here the effect i want to achieve playing with these div: http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page.html

The reason why i want to do like that is beacuse in the future maybe i will need to put a video there and i couldn do with background-image as i have done [here](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Home%20Page.html)

Comment: If you check the site you linked, the reason the image looks like it is behind the other elements is because of a single CSS setting: `background-attachment:fixed;` If you inspect the element in the debugger and remove that property from the `#home{}` style the image is not going to stay behind other divs but scroll along with it. Have you tried applying similar CSS to your code? Also, you link a fiddle with miles of HTML and inline-CSS on top of the CSS in the fiddle and ask for someone to make it work. The fiddle is very messy.

Comment: Hey Francois, this is the page i have built, i dont want to use background-attachment:fixed, i think i have explained in a very detailed way the issue.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't realise you build the page yourself. Still the fiddle is a mess, I can't even find my way around. I think the fiddle should be condensed into only the relevant elements focusing on the exact issue to solve. There should be no need to post the complete page into the fiddle. I also don't understand the requirements exactly you are trying to convey. Apologies again for not realising you build the linked site yourself.

Comment: @Manna Don't repost this question in an attempt to "bump" it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397192/scrolling-main-div-over-a-fixed-div-with-image-inside